# Is there a way to bound a generic type using an interface in Java?

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I am trying to create a generic list which sorts the items entered into it using the `.compareTo()` method of the type. However, I ran into a problem in the very first line. Since the type must be one which `implements Comparable<T>`, is there any way to enforce this? I suppose the syntax :

```
public class GenList<T implements Comparable<T>>{
//Class body.
}
```

won't work. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try that syntax first?

Comment: you can sort any List<T implements Comparable>  using `Collections.sort(list)` , no need to implement anything

Comment: No, its just a programming challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's a bit counter-intuitive, but for this you write `extends` rather than `implements`:

```
public class GenList<T extends Comparable<T>>{
//Class body.
}
```

(Note that I also changed the `?` to `T`, which I think is what you meant. A reference can have type `GenList<?>`, or type `GenList<? extends Comparable<String>>`, or whatnot, but it doesn't make sense to declare the class itself as taking a wildcard parameter.)

Answer (score 0):

You mean like

```
public class GenList<T extends Comparable<T>>{
//Class body.
}
```